# Advantage of Upper Type Bound over Subtyping

Tags: scala

What is the advantage of using upper type bounds over just type in this example?

Why people prefer this

```
trait Pages[T <: Page] {
  val pages: Seq[T]
  def find(id: String): Option[T] = pages.find(_.id == id)
  def all: Seq[T] = pages
}
```

Over this:

```
trait Pages {
  val pages: Seq[Page]
  def find(id: String): Option[Page] = pages.find(_.id == id)
  def all: Seq[Page] = pages
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the same as the advantage of your second example over

```
trait Pages {
  val pages: Seq[Any]
  def find(id: String): Option[Any] = pages.find(_.id == id)
  def all: Seq[Any] = pages
}
```

: more precise types, allowing you not to mix up different subtypes of `Page`, to access operations of `MyPage` without casting, etc.

Also, if you have the first and need the second, you can just use `Pages[Page]`; if you have the second and need the first, you are out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found out that in the first case I can specify type explicitly.
If `MyPage` is subtype if `Page`.

```
val pages = new Pages[MyPage]{
  override val pages: Seq[MyPage] = List(MyPage("a"), MyPage("b"))
}
```

And the compiler can infer the type so that `pages.find("a")` will be the `MyPage` type. In the second example the type always will be `Page`, which forces to cast it.