# Advantage of Upper Bound over Subtyping in Scala

Tags: scala

I know this question has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34182599/advantage-of-upper-type-bound-over-subtyping). But the answers there do not satisfy my doubt.
I was told that they prevent mix-up of class types, the code below shows that they're not mixed up at all.
So, it shouldn't matter right?

Classes:

```
package Practice

abstract class Animal {
  def name: String
}

abstract class Pet extends Animal {}

class Cat extends Pet {
  override def name: String = "Cat"
}

class Dog extends Pet {
  override def name: String = "Dog"
}
```

Here is the real confusion:

```
//Class with Upper Bound
class PetContainer[P <: Pet](p: P) {
  def pet: P = p
}

//Class with Subtyping(Or Upcasting, I think they're the same)
class SimplePetContainer(p: Pet){
  def pet: Pet = p
}
```

Driver Code:

```
val CatContainer: PetContainer[Cat] = new PetContainer[Cat](new Cat)
val DogContainer: SimplePetContainer = new SimplePetContainer(new Dog
println(CatContainer.pet.getClass)
println(DogContainer.pet.getClass)
```

Output:

```
class Practice.Cat
class Practice.Dog
//Practice was the package
```

Like I mentioned before, the classes are preserved.
So my question is, What advantage does Upper Bound have on Subtyping?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61852217/difference-of-upper-bounded-type-and-normal-class-behavior/61852358#61852358

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your `CatContainer`, you know that `CatContainer.pet` is a `Cat` at compile-time. Meaning that the compiler also knows that. So you can say

```
 CatContainer.pet.meow()
```

For the `SimplePetContainer` you do not have static type information about the `pet` inside anymore.

> Like I mentioned before, the classes are preserved.

At runtime, the `pet` of course still knows its type (well, almost, it knows its class, which in your case would have been enough, any extra type information such as the generic types of that class has been erased).
But the variable `DogContainer.pet` lacks information about what sort of `Pet` it contains.

> I was told that they prevent mix-up of class types

The compiler won't stop you from writing

```
val DogContainer = new SimplePetContainer(new Cat())
```

but it will reject this

```
val DogContainer = new PetContainer[Dog](new Cat())
```

Comment: At runtime Pet doesn't knows its type. There are not types at runtime. It knowns its class, but that is actually useless. Relying on class information in runtime is usually a bad design.